# Qt : How to make a dynamically added item not comply to style sheet set at design time

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I currently have a QToolBar that has the following style sheet

```
QToolBox::tab {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: darkgray;
    width: 70px;
}

QToolButton { /* all types of tool button */
    border: 2px solid #8f8f91;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #f6f7fa, stop: 1 #dadbde);
}

QToolButton[popupMode="1"] { /* only for MenuButtonPopup */
    padding-right: 30px; /* make way for the popup button */
}

QToolButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}

/* the subcontrols below are used only in the MenuButtonPopup mode */
QToolButton::menu-button {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    /* 16px width + 4px for border = 20px allocated above */
    width: 30px;
}
```

Now the problem with the above style sheet is that the `QToolButton` tag applies to every toolbutton that I add to the QtoolBar. Is there anyway to restrict the application of tis design to certain `QToolButton` that I add dynamically. The stylesheet is added at design time to the QToolBar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the objectName of the instancied QToolButton. In a QStyleSheet you can target specific instances of QtWidget inherited classes with #ObjectName.

exemple in sources :

```
QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget(parent);
pWidget->setObjectName("myWidget");
```

example in qss :

```
QWidget {
    background-color: red;
}

#myWidget {
    background-color: green;
}
```

for your widget with object name set as "myWidget", the background will be green, for all the others it will be red.

You will eventually need to polish() your widget if you dynamically update your stylesheet too. for this look at [Qt doc : polish()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcommonstyle.html#polish-3)